# How to make the ellipsis appear in the text

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Please refer the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Chamster/6ut0ve4s/) for details. Bottom line is that the style

```
.cutty {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

doesn't seem to force the dots when the button gets clicked., despit ethe fact that the enclosing parent has the style

```
.left {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

The aim is to ensure that the pink *cutty* gets most of the width in purple *left* while the brown *fixies* stay at the same width. Of course, I want to eliminate the wrap at white space and cut off the overflowing part.

The way my googling suggested is to make sure that the encapsulating parent is set to hide the overflow too. However, as show in the fiddle, that doesn't happen. There was also some mentioning about minimum width set to zero. Trying that gave nothing, though.

What do I miss?

Comment: display:flex + a really short word and no flex-basis nor width  makes the dot not appear https://jsfiddle.net/wyv6dsx0/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove `display: flex;` from `.cutty` is that what you wish to achieve?

Comment: Yes. But what if I wish *cutty* to be flex? It's possible that I want to keep a bunch of elements in it, not only text and that the layout of those needs to be governed by flexbox... You're welcome to elaborate on why/how of this issue.

Comment: Also, another follow up, if I remove *display:flex*, what should I replace it by? In the production code, I'm getting inherited flex on all my spans and divs and can't control it. How do I get rid of flex? Setting *none* will remove the component... I tried *block* and *inline* but that didn't gave a change...

Comment: @KonradViltersten any display value will do the reset, block or inline, it is a flex child, it will behave as a flex child :)

Comment: @G-Cyr Stupid... So stupid... (Not you, of course. Me...) I guess it's time to pack up and head home. Too much CSS per day will kill you. It's 20:44 so I should leave work way long time ago...)